# If statement in LINQ where clause C#

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I have written a query, and was wondering how I could implement an if statement in the where clause so that the "category_id" filter can only be added if the value is set. If the "category_id" value is null, then it would not complete the statement. Basically I am trying to make this statement into a toggle when inputting through SQL

```
var r = from lh in db.lh_url
        where lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_id
        where lh.first_id >= id
        where lh.first_id < (id + BatchSize)
        orderby ph.url, ph.vendor, ph.product
        select new
        {
            lh
        };
```

Comment: If *what* value is set?

Comment: `where clientInfo.cf.category_id == null || lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_id`?

Comment: if the category_id value is set for the clientInfo.cf file

Comment: are you trying to get pages?  if so I would recomend `.Skip(...)` + `.Take(...)`

Comment: _"...then it would not complete the statement"_ -- check for `null` is easy. Understanding what you mean by "not complete the statement", not so much. You can't check the `category_id` field of elements within the query without executing the query. And "the statement" here is the entire query. Please explain exactly what it is you're trying to do. Provide a good [mcve], describe what that code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the extension methods you can stack them:

```
if (clientInfo.cf.category_id != null)
    db.lh_url.Where(lh => lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_id);
```

However, using the inline syntax, I prefer to use short circuits:

```
bool useCategory = clientInfo.cf.category_id != null;

var r = from lh in db.lh_url
        where (!useCategory || lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_Id)
        ....
```

*NOTE: I've extracted the boolean conditional into a variable because when dealing with a DataContext, the expression may attempt to evaluate your object into a SQL expression which will cause failures.*

Comment: thanks. where would I put the if statement? would it be within the query?

Comment: @LucasHan: In the inline syntax there is no "if" condition needed. The where clause using the `||` causes the condition to be evaluated properly in either case. Using the boolean `useCategory`, if the category_id is null, it's the same as saying `where true` which retrieves all of the records. If it's not null, then that condition fails and it proceeds to the second half which evaluates to `where category_id = cf.category_id`

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant something like this:

```
var r = from lh in db.lh_url
        where clientInfo.cf.category_id != null 
        && lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_id
        && lh.first_id >= id
        && lh.first_id < (id + BatchSize)
        orderby ph.url, ph.vendor, ph.product
        select new
        {
            lh
        };
```

Comment: did you mean "where clientInfo.cf.category_id != null? or did you purposely only use clientInfo.cf

Comment: @LucasHan now i see the user's latest comments. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
where (lh.category_id == null || lh.category_id == clientInfo.cf.category_id)
       && lh.first_id >= id
       && lh.first_id < (id + BatchSize)
```